# Remix session update in the strategy without redirect

Tags: auth0, remix.run

I am integrated auth0 to the remix.run app and now trying to save access token that issued on the login:

```
import { createCookieSessionStorage } from "@remix-run/node";
import { getOrThrow } from "~/utils/env";

export const sessionStorage = createCookieSessionStorage({
  cookie: {
    name: "_session", // use any name you want here
    sameSite: "lax", // this helps with CSRF
    path: "/", // remember to add this so the cookie will work in all routes
    httpOnly: true, // for security reasons, make this cookie http only
    secrets: [getOrThrow("SERVER_SESSION_SECRET")], // replace this with an actual secret
    secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === "production", // enable this in prod only
  },
});

const { getSession, commitSession, destroySession } = sessionStorage;

let auth0Strategy = new Auth0Strategy(
  {
    callbackURL: getOrThrow("AUTH0_CALLBACK_URL"),
    clientID: getOrThrow("AUTH0_CLIENT_ID"),
    clientSecret: getOrThrow("AUTH0_CLIENT_SECRET"),
    domain: getOrThrow("AUTH0_DOMAIN"),
  },
  async ({ profile, accessToken, refreshToken, request }) => {
    const user: User = {
      .....
      // Convert `profile: Auth0Profile` to my data type
    }

    const session = await getSession(request.headers.get("Cookie"));
    session.set("accessToken", accessToken)
    session.set("refreshToken", refreshToken)

    const cookie = await commitSession(session);

    // HERE: `cookie` contains new cookie with my data

    return user;
  }
);
```

About place marked "HERE" in the code I have couple of questions:

1. how to promote it from here to the actual session? It is not an action or loader, I cannot throw redirect from here.
2. I don't like idea to send sensitive data to the cookied even if it is encrypted. Can you recommend example that demonstrates how to keep special "session" on server only?

Answer (score -1):

Remix provides additional session storage strategies besides cookies: memory, file, Cloudflare Workers KV, etc.

You can also create a custom session strategy to store session data in a database or Redis, for example.

https://remix.run/docs/en/main/utils/sessions